# Selenium IDE javascript strip last character

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I am wanting to strip the last letter of a variable in selenium IDE and store in a variable.

I've tried

```
${projectName}.slice(0, -4)
${projectName}.slice(0, -1)

Looking to get ksGHMOP from ksGHMOPW
```

Comment: Please try, 
**${projectName}.slice(0, 7)**

Answer (score 1):

Close!

Give this bit a go:

```
var projectNameLess = ${projectName}.substr(0, ${projectName}.length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that takes variable x and slices off the last element and stores it in variable a.

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>ksGHMOPW</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${x}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['x'].slice(0,-1);</td>
    <td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${a}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

You need to do the slicing in javascript, so you need to use storedVars to access the selenium variables in javascript.
Let me know if you need further explanation.